# List of acronyms with avoiding pages written in the margin (acro package)

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, acro

I am using the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) package for writing a list of acronyms. My acronyms appear in a lot of pages in my document and when I want to generate the list of acronyms the pages are displayed in the right margin. However, due to the large number of pages for some acronyms, the list of pages go outside of the page.

Is it possible to force to display the pages inside the page (and if possible avoiding to display it in the margin)?

**(M)WE:** (see also [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zwctwyggrjrh))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{first-style=short,list-style=lof}
\DeclareAcronym{testA}{
  short = testA ,
  long  = {AA Super long acronym with a lot a text for describing it and appearing in many pages}
}
\DeclareAcronym{testB}{
  short = testB ,
  long  = {BB Super long acronym with a lot a text for describing it and appearing in many pages}
}

\title{Test acronym}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Your abstract.
\end{abstract}
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage
\ac{testA}
\newpage
\ac{testB}
\newpage


\printacronyms[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be an option for you to switch to `glossaries` package?

Comment: I am using the `acro` because it does not require any index processor. I am using the list of acronyms in a scientific article and it could be nice to avoid to use specific tools for compilation. But if it is not possible to obtain what I want with `acro`, I will change it.

Comment: I've updated my TeX distribution and can't compile this, since `acro` uses `l3sort` which is now deprecated. Until @clemens does not update `acro`, this is difficult to track

Comment: It's possible to use `glossaries` without any index processor (although it's slower). See ["Option 1"](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#option1) in the user manual. There are [plenty of predefined styles](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/).

Comment: Are you tied to `list-style=lof`, along with one of `page-style=plain|comma|paren` you might find it easier to use a table-based `list-style` to keep everything in the page width.

Comment: @clemens OK thank you. Do you have any idea of when you think you will solve it?

Comment: @clemens: Noted, but since you're here you can do the job ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `acro`'s `lof` style uses `\@dottedtocline` for the entries. `\@dottedtocline` uses an `\hbox` with a width of `\@pnumwidth` (which is defined by the document class) for typesetting the page numbers.

This is not designed to take a list or range of page numbers. In `acro` v3.x they are disabled in the `toc` and `lof` styles exactly for this reason.

For `acro` v2.x my advice is to set `\acsetup{pages=first}`.

Of course one could increase `\@pnumwidth` but that would affect the lists of tables and figures etc. as well and could require quite large values which in the end will not look very good. Not a solution IMHO.