# How to set the width of the pages column in printacronyms of acro package

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, acronyms, acro

I am using the acro package to manage my abbreviations and other symbols.
Thus I have defined a class for these acronyms and would like to a list for each class in the style of the list of figures.

The problem I am facing is, that the number of pages is so large, that they are resulting in overfull hboxes in the list of acronyms.
The width of this column seems to handle numbers with two digits fine, but afterwards it is too small. I found the option list-short-width to adjust the size for the abbreviations, but can't find a similar one for the pages.

My question is thus: How can I adjust the size of this column in the list?

The problem was reproduced at least with acro v2.8 and v2.9.
A minimum working example to reproduce the problem is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[version=2]{acro} % Use this for newer versions of acro
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
  list-short-width = 4.2em,
  list-style = lof,
  macros = true,
  xspace = true,
  pages = first,
  page-style=plain
}

\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}[1][List of Abbreviations]{\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=#1]}

\newcommand{\abbr}[3]{
\DeclareAcronym{#1}{
  short = #2 ,
  long  = #3 ,
  first-style=default ,
  class = abbrev
}}

\abbr{FA}{FA}{First Abbreviation}
\abbr{ABCDE}{ABCDE}{My Abc Song}
\abbr{AO}{AO}{Alpha and Omega}

\begin{document}
\FA
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{42}
\ABCDE
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{999}
\AO
\newpage 

\listofabbreviations

\end{document}
```

This will result in
`Overfull \hbox (6.72215pt too wide) detected at line 40`

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The problem is similar to the also unanswered [List of acronyms with avoiding pages written in the margin (acro package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353208/list-of-acronyms-with-avoiding-pages-written-in-the-margin-acro-package), though not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the `lof` style of `acro`'s list (both versions 2.x and 3.x) the entries are written with `\@dottedtocline`. This is used by the list of tables and list of figures as well for their entries.  `\@dottedtocline` sets the page numbers in an `\hbox` of width `\@pnumwidth`.

The `article` class defines

```
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
```

so all you need to do is choose a larger value. With

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{1.8em}
\makeatother
```

I get

[image]